# What is the name of the technique of introducing a character via a (often monocoloured) freeze frame?

Tags: film-techniques

In the movie snatch (among others) the characters are introduced via a mono coloured freeze frame with the name of the character next to it. An example of this can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8jbt0wBkMI) at the 1:22 minute mark.

What is this technique called?

Comment: Never heard of a term for that, personally. But will happily be schooled if there is. ;)

Comment: I saw the name the other day for the "technique" but can't find the link. [Here is a link](http://www.watchthetitles.com/articles/0094-The_Good_The_Bad_and_The_Ugly) to The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly, where Guy Richie definitely had inspiration from (or the person creating the title sequence, if he didn't request that effect). The article or comment I was reading pointed the person asking about Snatch to that movie intro sequence, and I ended up watching the whole movie.

Answer (score 7):

It's simply called the [freeze-frame shot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-frame_shot). It's employed for all manner of purposes, including introducing characters.